# Safe conversion from one InnoDB(ibdata) file to innodb file per table

Tags: mysql, configuration, innodb

I have MySQL database with tables on InnoDB engine. But server is configured to use only one file ibdata0 without parameter innodb_file_per_table. I want to change this without making dump and restore it on reconfigured server. So my plan was to add parameter `innodb_file_per_table` in my.cnf restart server and force with `ALTER TABLE` to rebuild all InnoDB tables.

Doing `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE = InnoDB` should create `.idb` file for every `.frm` file in my `/val/lib/mysql/mydatabase` directory and it did (and I thought move data from `ibdata` file). But after I shut down the server and removed the old ibdata file I see all tables (`SHOW TABLES`) but if I make any `SELECT` in them I get this error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mytable' doesn't exist
```

So I suppose that some of the data remained in the old ibdata file.

Have I omitted something? Is there a way to do what I want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are going to have to do a dump and restore. Even after doing the `alter table engine` trick, some data will remain in the ibdata1 file.

- Dump all innodb tables to external files
- Drop all innodb tables
- Shut down mysql
- Remove ibdata1 (and any logfiles if they exist)
- Start mysql
- Import sql dump files

I have run into this issue myself, and dumping all the tables and then re-importing them without shutting down mysql doesnt work. All innodb tables must be gone before you can remove the ibdata1 file.

Comment: You are right... it works only that way.